# Start a graphql-yoga server in the NextJS api folder

Tags: graphql, next.js

Could anyone please explain to me how I can start a GraphQL-Yoga server in the NextJS **/api/** folder?

So far I have a **graphql.js** file inside of the **pages/api** folder and the code looks like this.

```
import { GraphQLServer } from 'graphql-yoga';

const typeDefs = `
  type Query {
    hello(name: String): String!
  }
`;

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    hello: (_, { name }) => `Hello ${name || 'World'}`,
  },
};

const server = new GraphQLServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });
server.start(() => console.log('Server is running on localhost:4000'));
```

My expectation was that I could enter localhost:4000 and enter the graphql-yoga playground where I can test my queries after starting it just like when I run this code in a Node JS project. NextJS runs as normal after I initiate **npm run dev**, but the graphql-yoga code doesn't seem to run.
All advice is appreciated - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you update your code to use `@graphql-yoga/node` and define the endpoint in server options you can access the Yoga GraphiQL playground at localhost:3000/api/graphql (or whatever port you Next.JS server is using). See the `graphql.js` file below or full [Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/next-js-yoga-graphiql-lf6ktu).

```js
// pages/api/graphql.js
import { createServer } from "@graphql-yoga/node";

const typeDefs = `
  type Query {
    hello(name: String): String!
  }
`;

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    hello: (_, { name }) => `Hello ${name || "World"}`
  }
};

const server = createServer({
  schema: { typeDefs, resolvers, endpoint: "/api/graphql" }
});

export default server;
```